# Regular expression match phone number with [a|b] pattern

Tags: regex

I've phone numbers like following formats,

```
415-555-1234
(416)555-3456
202 555 4567
4035555678
1 416 555 9292
```

I'm going to match all of them with this expression,

```
[\(|\d\s]?\d{3}[-|\)\s]?\d{3}[-|\s]?\d{4}
```

It matches all except the last one. The leading `"1 "` of last phone number can't be matched. 
I'm wondering why this expression doesn't work. Why can't `\d\s` match the leading `"1 "` of last phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing the square brackets. They hold a character class which infers that any item from the list should be matched. Use this instead:

```
^(?:\(|\d\s)?\d{3}[-\)\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/qF6dL0/2)!

---

However, the above only fixes your regex errors. To match the actual complete format of your test cases, you should use this regex instead:

```
^(?:\d\s)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(\s|(-)?)?\d{3}(?(2)-|(?(1)\s|-?))\d{4}$
```

- `^` Start of string.
- `(?:\d\s)?` Optional digit-whitespace sequence.
- `(?:` Group
- - `\(\d{3}\)` Three digits in brackets.
- - `|` *OR*
- - `\d{3}` Three digits.
- `)`
- `(\s|(-)?)?` Capturing group: Optional white space or hyphen. Second capturing group tries to capture a hyphen.
- `\d{3}` Three digits.
- `(?(2)` If we matched the hyphen, then:
- - `-` Match a hyphen here.
- - `|` **ELSE**
- - `(?(1)` If we matched the whitespace, then:
- - - `\s` Match a whitespace here.
- - - `|` **ELSE**
- - - `-?` Match a hyphen, if you want.
- - `)`
- `)`
- `\d{4}` Four digits.
- `$` End of string.

Here is an [UPDATED regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aS0yO1/1)!

---

However, the above matches the syntax, but doesn't capture the numbers. To capture the numbers, you have to expand the above regex to the following:

```
^(?:\d\s)?(?|\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))(?|-(\d{3})-|\s(\d{3})\s|(\d{3})-?)(\d{4})$
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aS0yO1/2)! Please note that capturing groups 1, 2, and 3 holds the first three, next three, and the last four numbers in the phone number.

Comment: Could you explain why you use a non-capturing group at here `(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})` ? I tried to remove the `?:` and expected it to match either `(416)` or `416` like a `(a|b)` pattern. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Takumar Here we are asserting that for the first three digits, they are either entirely surrounded by brackets or not. To do that, we can either use a conditional or an alternation within a group. Since we do not need to capture it, we used a non-capturing group. To capture the three sets of numbers, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I totally understand now. Magic regex!

Answer (score 1):

Because `[\(|\d\s]` does not do what you think it does. It is a character class that matches either `(`, `|`, any digit from 0-9, or any whitespace character. You don't need a character class here.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
(?:\d )?\(?\d{3} ?\)?-?\d{3} ?-?\d{4}
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qP0lJ9/1)

Comment: According to definition, `[a|b]` should match a or b; so I think `[\(|\d\s]` should match either `(` or `0-9 `, is it right?

Comment: @Takumar: No, that's incorrect. `[a|b]` matches `a`, the literal character `|`, or `b`.

Comment: @AmalMurali, @Unihedron Yeah, you're right. I misuse the `[]` and `()`. Thanks.

Comment: @Takumar: Just a note: this regex will match many invalid phone numbers as well. It's fine so long as you're trying to **extract** them from a block of text or something, but you may need to be more strict if you're going to use this for validation purposes.

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm new to regex but still curious about what's a robust validation code looks like. What additional checking should be added?

Comment: @Unihedron well, this is just a practice from RegexOne.com. I'm new to regex