# Checking if string starts with two numericals - Regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace

With the help of http://www.regexr.com/ I created this preg_replace:

```
preg_replace("/\+[\d]{2}|\(0\)|\(|\)|\s/","",$number);
```

which changes any of these

```
+27123456789
+27 12 345 6789
(+27)123456789
(+27) 12 345 6789
+27 (0) 12 345 6789
+27(0)123456789
012 345 6789
0123456789
```

into `0123456789` (South African phone number format)

However, it doesn't change these two and no matter how I set it up, it doesn't want to work:

```
27 (0) 12 345 6789
27(0)123456789
```

How can I change the regex match so that it works with those as well?

Comment: What should `27 (0) 12 345 6789` become?

Comment: Also `0123456789`. This is in a parser to get all the formats the same.

Comment: ok can you show expected output in your question.

Comment: `+27123456789` will be changed into `123456789`, not `0123456789`. Does it matter?

Comment: Yes it does, it must display a 0 there. If it's not possible I can just do a manual check there.

Comment: Similar question: [Regular expression match phone number with \[a|b\] pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25336913/3622940)

Comment: Try this regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation/20971688#20971688  It's a "bit" overkill, but works for you. It matches the formats you have and many more (including extensions). I believe you can easily change it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a few pass for easier manipulation. Click on example to see the visualization.

1. `\+[\d]{2}|[()]` to remove `+27`, `(` and `)`. [Example](http://regex101.com/r/bL4eW2/8)
2. `[ ]+` to remove all the spaces in between. [Example](http://regex101.com/r/bL4eW2/9)
3. `(^\d{9}(?=$))` replace with `0\1` to add a **0** if it's only 9 digits long.

**EDIT1:**
As @Alan Moore pointed out for 3,we don't need look ahead for $. So `(^\d{9}$)` will suffice. [Example](http://regex101.com/r/pC1yP6/2)

**EDIT2:**
Since the author wanna match `27(0)...`, just add an additional step 4 as below.

4. `270?(\d{9})` replace with `0\1`. Match numbers starting with 27(0) and replace with 0 and the last 9 digits. [Example](http://regex101.com/r/sJ0zN4/2)

Note: you need to enable '**g**' modifier for the first two and '**gm**' modifier for the last one. We need **m** because we wanna match `^` at the start of each line.

Comment: `$` is already a zero-width assertion; you don't need to wrap it in a lookahead.

Comment: Oh ya. Good catch! It's a mistake because I've been messing around with look ahead/behind for this few days. I'll update it.

Comment: This doesn't remove just plain 27... it leaves the 27 there.

Comment: The current design is built on the example that you gave. It will match only `+27` altogether. If `+` is not present, it will not match anything. So you wanna match `27123456789` as well?

Comment: If you wanna match `27(0)...`, just add this as a step 4. `27(?:0?)(\d{9})` replace with `0\1`. See [here](http://regex101.com/r/sJ0zN4/1).

Comment: You are welcome. Btw `(?:0?)` is redundant and can be replace with `0?` as seen in the answer EDIT2.